# Помогите, мне нужно написать функцию removeZeros, которая принимает целое число n и возвращает новое число состоящее из всех цифр n кроме нулей

Tags: javascript

```
function removeZeros(number) {
  // код здесь
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я считаю коссвенным методом решение этой задачи путём преобразования цифр в строку и потом обратно строку в число. Есть математический алгоритм, который работает только с числами. Посмотреть можно по [этой ссылке](http://opan.strana.de/stack/removezeros.html). (см. исходный код)

Answer (score 2):

```
let number = 128010101300012331;
console.log((number +'').replaceAll('0', ''));
```

Comment: Думал мой вариант краткий, а тут ваш вариант, число со стройкой сложить, ловко конечно -- супер! +

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeZeros(number) {
    let string = number.toString();     // Преобразуем число в строку
    let number_array = string.split('');    // Разобьем строку на элементы
    var i = "";
    number_array.forEach(function callback(Value) {
        if (Value != 0){
            i += Value;     // Добавим к новой строке все кроме нулей
        }
    });
    return +i;      // + Преобразует строку в число
}
```

Comment: есть решение буквально в 30 сиволов длиной. Что это за монстр?))

Comment: я решил выиграть чемпионат по самым длинным ответам)

Comment: Надо было ещё имена переменных тогда назвать типа "numberThatShouldBeCleanedFromZeros" и "numberAsStringRepresentation" и т.д. 

Answer (score 0):

**Можно такой вариант через `replace`.**

Сперва преобразовали в строку `number.toString()`

Из этой строки вырезали все нули `number.toString().replace(/0/g, '')`

И знак `+` преобразовали снова в число

```js
const removeZeros = (number) => +(number.toString().replace(/0/g, ''))

console.log(removeZeros(101))
console.log(removeZeros(10102312000012313))
console.log(removeZeros(1020))
```